# Does Google Maps API provides turn by turn if there are no WIFI or GSM signals

Tags: google-maps, indoor-positioning-system, google-indoor-maps

Was wondering if Google Maps API provide turn by turn directions if there are no WIFI or GSM signals? Will it provide navigation as well?

Thanks guys!

Comment: umm, why do i get a downvote? please provide reason?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should download the map before being offline, then you can use google map.

Comment: So, routing or the directions API will work without gps or gsm signal?

Comment: GPS is needed to use the map without WiFi. To be able to do it, search for a place where you want to go, then touch the bar that has the name of the place you searched, then touch menu button which is at top right, then select save offline map to save the selected area.

Comment: Yes I understand the concept of it, but I m asking about routing or providing turn by turn directions when there is no GPS, no WIFI and no GSM signals... I guess I m talking about basement parking... would google maps able to provide turn by turn directions (just polygon lines, no need for navigation)